# htaccess directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+).php website.com/admin/index.php?route=$1/$2 [NS]
RewriteRule ^modules/([^/]+)/([^/]+).php website.com/admin/index.php?route=$1/$2 [NS]
```

the above works for when you login. it goes to `/admin/modules/catalog` but when you click on a link that shows up in the status bar as `/admin/vendors/` it doesnt work???? which vendors is a sub dir or modules/

any idea

Comment: You should be more specific about what the actual error is.

Answer (score 2):

Considering what is said in the documentation about [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), and what you get, I'd say that the RewriteConditions are only applied to the one RewriteRule that follows :

> The RewriteCond directive defines a
>   rule condition. One or more
>   RewriteCond  can precede a RewriteRule
>   directive. The following rule is then
>   only used if both the current state of
>   the URI matches its pattern, and if
>   these conditions are met.

What if you try duplicating those RewriteCond in front of the second RewriteRule ? At least as a test ?

And here is an [interesting thing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_s) about the S|Skip flag. Amongst other things and an example, it is said :

> The `[S]` flag is used to skip rules
>   that you don't want to run. This can
>   be thought of as a goto statement in
>   your rewrite ruleset.

And also :

> This technique is useful because a
>   RewriteCond only applies to the
>   RewriteRule immediately following it.
>   Thus, if you want to make a
>   RewriteCond apply to several
>   RewriteRules, one possible technique
>   is to negate those conditions and use
>   a `[Skip]` flag.

I've never tried this, but it might be useful, in your situation... maybe ^^

*Still, it's some part of the Apache's documentation that seem to indicate what I said earlier is right.*

Comment: "RewriteConditions are only applied to the one RewriteRule that follows" Didn't even catch that, nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming poor English?
It sounds like you're requesting /admin/vendors; but you're saying that vendors is located in /modules.